# How to check for git uncommited changes in a script?

Tags: git, shell, commit

In a script I want to check that there are no uncommited changes so that I can switch to a different branch (and then switch back). What is the proper way how to do such a check?

Comment: Have you tried `git status`?

Comment: @viakondratiuk I'm hoping for a git command whose exit status would show if there are any changes or not. I could use something like `git status | grep -q modified`, but I'm not sure if this is really safe even in corner cases (like if there is an untracked file named `modified` etc.).

Comment: @PetrPudlák Are you interested only in *modified* files, i.e. don't care about untracked files?

Comment: @devnull Yes, I'm primarily interested only in _modified_ files.

Comment: @PetrPudlák You could say `git status -s | grep -q "^ M" && echo Modified files exist!`

Comment: Do you need to check this explicitly? `git checkout` will fail if cannot switch branches because switching would cause an uncommitted change to be overridden. (You can still carry uncommitted changes to the new branch and back again.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey don't want to carry changes and accidentally commit them there.